# remove few property from enums in typescript based on environment

Tags: typescript, enums

I want to remove certain enum property based on environment.

e.g - in the build environment , i need all the enums

```
export enum ERROR_TYPE {
    InvalidComponent = 'invalid_component',
    ForOnPrimitiveOrNull = "for_on_primitive|null",
    InvalidEventHandler = "invalid_event_handler",
    InvalidFormatter = "invalid_formatter",
    PropDataTypeMismatch = "prop_data_type_mismatch",
    RendererNotFound = "createRenderer_not_found",
    MutatingProp = "mutating_prop",
    SetSameValue = "set_same_value"
}
```

but for production environment, i only need few property from the enums like a subset

```
export enum ERROR_TYPE {
    InvalidComponent = 'invalid_component',
    ForOnPrimitiveOrNull = "for_on_primitive|null",
    InvalidEventHandler = "invalid_event_handler",
    InvalidFormatter = "invalid_formatter",
}
```

How can i do that ? If not what's the best practice, is there any alternative ?

I want to remove these codes, because they are not going to be used in prod environment, but they are contributing to the bundle size.

Comment: Use an es module instead of an enum. That is export each enum member as a const.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of thinking i found the best way -

In order to get the static typing - i am creating an interface

```
export interface IErrorType {
    InvalidComponent: 'invalid_component';
    InvalidFormatter: "invalid_formatter";
    PropDataTypeMismatch: "prop_data_type_mismatch";
    RendererNotFound: "createRenderer_not_found";
    ForOnPrimitiveOrNull: "for_on_primitive|null";
    InvalidEventHandler: "invalid_event_handler";
    SetSameValue: "set_same_value";
    MutatingProp: "mutating_prop";
}
```

so all my errors are in the interface `IErrorType`

now i converted my enums into a constant with type `IErrorType` and assigning the development environment enums with a condition. This make sure that only production related enums are in production bundled.

```
export const ERROR_TYPE = {
    InvalidComponent: 'invalid_component',
    InvalidFormatter: "invalid_formatter",
    PropDataTypeMismatch: "prop_data_type_mismatch",
} as any as IErrorType;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    Object.assign(ERROR_TYPE, {
        ForOnPrimitiveOrNull: "for_on_primitive|null",
        InvalidEventHandler: "invalid_event_handler",
        SetSameValue: "set_same_value",
        MutatingProp: "mutating_prop",
        RendererNotFound: "createRenderer_not_found",
    });
}
```